# How to get iOS app to work on all iPhones? (Constraints)

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, constraints

I am fairly new to developing for iOS. I have a fully functioning program written in Swift and the UI was created in the scene builder on Xcode. I created an app for my work to simplify closing out the registers and other financial aspects. The app is complete and works perfectly, but was designed on the iPhoneX. The problem is that only a few of the employees have an iPhoneX, but they all have some kind of iPhone. I have tried setting up constraints but it never works. Ive tried scaling restraints and position restraints but I can't get the layout to look right on any other phone, and when I add the constraints it affects the view on the iPhoneX as well and doesn't look good on any iPhone. I need help getting this to work on all iPhones. I would like it to look and act the exact same regardless of the size of the phone, basically just scaled down. There are a lot of things on the screen and I can't figure out how to do this. Please help!!!

I have been working on this for a long time and I really need help. Please let me know if I need to clarify anything. I have posted links to some pictures of my UI so you have an idea of whats going on.

[Constraints I tried adding, although I have played around with some other options.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/squ02.jpg)

[Here's what it looks like on the iPhoneX, this is how I want it to look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMy7T.jpg)

[What it looks like on iPhoneSE (with constraints).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhTgB.jpg)

Comment: I wil help you for first ROW.

Comment: You can modify those constraints in code for different devices separately.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed in your Xcode project that none of your features are in UIView. Without it, it will be quite challenging and somewhat always different results. In theory, if you use AutoLayout features correctly it should work without UIView, but they make life so much easier. This is something I learned the hard way at the beginning of my iOS development. First set up your UIViews without any content inside it, give them some background colour to differentiate, once they are working on all devices. You can pin your features to superviews with no difficulty.

Since you have a repetitive features, you could also consider using Stack Views. You don't have complicated features, so as long as AutoLayout is set up correctly you should have no problems seeing it ok on all devices